Android Studio is stuck at "Starting download..." screen for a while now
Android studio is stuck at "Starting download...." screen and not moving forward from an hour almost.
Image attached for reference.

It is taking longer than expected. Not showing any progress or any indication if it's stuck somewhere or working in the background.

Cancel it and retry?

Tried but again taking way long to proceed and stuck on the screen

I faced the same issue while installing it, i was trying to install koala 2024.1 version in my Kali 2024.3 system, i continued to stay on the page where the downloading part was stuck for some time and it worked for me. I read somewhere online, similar thing has happened to other users too..
Which OS are you using ?

I was trying it on my windows machine. It also worked for me after a few cancellation and retry.
